# Php email with images not showing in Outllook and Android Gmail

Tags: php, email

I am sending an email with php. I have 3 images as table backgrounds as I was advised to do. The problem is that I can not see the email images when viewing it in Outlook nad Adroid Gmail app.

Here is the code used:

```
$headers = "From:  Furniture \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: info@furniture.com \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

$message = '<html><body style="margin: 0;">';
$message .= '<table background="http://mysite.com/emailfinal1.jpg" border="0" width="650" height="506" style="font-family: arial, tahoma;color: black; margin: 0;">
<tr height="308" width="650"><td width="450"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr height="16" width="650" style="font-size:12px;"><td width="450">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" valign="bottom">'. $first_name . ' ' . $last_name . '</td></tr>
<tr height="16" width="650" style="font-size:12px;"><td width="450">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" valign="bottom">'. $email . '</td></tr>
<tr height="16" width="650" style="font-size:12px;"><td width="450">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" valign="bottom">'. $nextdate . '</td></tr>
<tr height="134" width="650"><td width="450"></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
<table background="http://mysite.com/emailfinal2.jpg" border="0" width="650" height="133" style="font-family: arial, tahoma;color: #29468a; margin: 0;">
<tr height="10" width="650"><td width="175"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr height="123" width="650" style="font-size:13px;"><td width="175">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" valign="baseline"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/unsubscribe.php" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color: #29468a;">UNSUBSCRIBE</a> | <a href="http://www.mysite.com/Terms-And-Conditions.aspx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color: #29468a;">TERMS & CONDITIONS</a></td></tr>
</table>
<table background="http://mysite.com/emailfinal3.jpg" border="0" width="650" height="60" style="font-family: arial, tahoma;color: #29468a; margin: 0;">
<tr height="20" width="650"><td width="526"></td><td></td></tr>
<tr height="40" width="650" style="font-size:11px;"><td width="526">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" valign="baseline"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/Contact-Us.aspx" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none;color: #29468a;">Contact Us</a></td></tr>
</table>';
$message .= "</body></html>";
```

Any advices? Am I in the wrong direction? I want to make the email show the images by default.

Answer (score 2):

Many mail clients default to not display images that are externally linked in an email like yours are. This is done for security reasons (so that if I open a spam email, it doesn't automatically make http requests to the spammer's site to fetch the images, as that would allow the spammer to track me).

Most mail clients do offer the user the option to load the messages afterward, but that's not always ideal (and a lot of users don't bother -- I don't usually).

The solution is to embed the images in the email itself, so they are part of the message. Most mail clients that block external images will happily display embedded images. This is done using a specially constructed multi-part message, but I wouldn't recommend trying to built it yourself.

If you're not doing so already (it doesn't look like you are), then I suggest using a decent mailer class like phpMailer or Swiftmailer instead of the raw PHP `mail()` function. You'll get a lot more functionality, including things like the ability to embed images into your mail. This should help you get around your problem. (as a bonus, it will also likely make your code much cleaner and easier to work with).

Answer (score 0):

Developing email for compatibility across a number of email clients is difficult as they each have their own support for HTML and CSS.  You might want to strongly consider using an email preview tool when developing your email. You could just be having your images blocked (as is default on many email clients these days).  Basically my advice would be to not depend on images for layout or readability of your email.

Here is an article with links to several email preview tools:

http://www.smartinsights.com/email-marketing/email-creative-and-copywriting/email-preview-tools/

Comment: I wish I would not depend on images but some times those are the only way. I have tried on of the sites to preview my email and things are better than I thought :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually the e-mail clients block access to external images for security / privacy reasons.
Make sure your have added the sender's e-mail address to the white-list.

If it is your case, you cannot do much for it because it is an issue on the clients' side.
A better approach is to provide a hyperlink to your website with a text like this:

> In case you cannot view the image below, click here.

Comment: The hyperlink is the easy solution. I was considering it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

first you have have to install phpmailer library in your application, then add cid:image1,cid:image2,cid:image3 in your image tag src. then call mail sending function like below it will display images in all browsers with out mail spamming issue.

```
        $mail             = new PHPMailer();
        $body             = $body;
        $body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
        $mail->Host       = "";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
        $mail->Port       = 25;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
        $mail->Username   = "";  // GMAIL username
        $mail->Password   = '';            // GMAIL password
        $mail->SetFrom($fr_email, ');
        $mail->AddReplyTo("");
        $mail->Subject    = $sub;
        $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

        $mail->MsgHTML($body);
        $address = $to;
        $mail->AddAddress($address, "");
        $mail->AddAddress('rikinadhyapak@gmail.com', "");      
        $notificationpos1 = strpos(strtolower($sub), 'notification');
        $notificationpos2 = strpos(strtolower($sub), 'lead');      
        if($notificationpos1 === false && $notificationpos2 === false){
            //Attach an image file
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/image1.jpg','image1');
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/image1.jpg','image2');      
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('images/image2.jpg','image3');      
           // attach file logo.jpg, and later link to it using identfier logoimg
        }
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
              echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
              echo "Message sent!";
            }
```